# GetStream creates same activity in different feeds

Tags: javascript, feed, getstream-io

I built this piece of code to add tags to my **tag feed**.

```
buildActivity = (model,obj) => {
  return {
    ...{
      actor: `user:model.user`,
      verb: 'is',
      object: `model:${model.id}`,
      foreign_id: `model:${model.id}`,
      time: model.createdAt.toDate(),
    },
    ...(obj ? obj : {})
  }
}
addActivitiesToTagFeed = async (model,tags) => {
  const promises = []
  for(let i=0;i<tags.length;i++){
    const tag = tags[i]
    const activity = buildActivity(model,{target: `tag:${tag}`})
    const feed = stream.feed('tag', tag)
    promises.push(feed.addActivity(activity))
  }
  await Promise.all(promises)
}
```

Which I limited to max 3 tags. I can have like
`tag:netflix`
`tag:films`
`tag:suspense`

The problem is somehow the activity created by **addActivity** is the same to all tags. The same target, even the same activity id. It is breaking my 'tag_aggregated' that only follows one of those tags.

Ideas anyone how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Good news**

Feeds (in my case `tag` feed) can't have differents activities with same **foreign_id + time**. To fixed I changed my code

```
buildActivity = (model,obj) => {
  return {
    ...{
      actor: `user:model.user`,
      verb: 'is',
      object: `model:${model.id}`,
      foreign_id: `model:${model.id}`,
      time: model.createdAt.toDate(),
    },
    ...(obj ? obj : {})
  }
}
addActivitiesToTagFeed = async (model,tags) => {
  const promises = []
  for(let i=0;i<tags.length;i++){
    const tag = tags[i]

    // THIS LINE changing the foreign_id for each activity
    const activity = buildActivity(model,{target: `tag:${tag}`,foreign_id: `model:${model.id}:${tag}`})

    const feed = stream.feed('tag', tag)
    promises.push(feed.addActivity(activity))
  }
  await Promise.all(promises)
}
```

It fixed my problem. In GetStream documentation doesn't mention it but makes sense, because `foreign_id` + `time` is a secondary key to find unique record.